# What is the difference between "Paying in cash" and "Paying with cash"?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, grammaticality-in-context

What is the difference between the following sentences?

1. I paid with cash
2. I paid in cash

Could I use the word "money" instead of cash?

Comment: Not really: **money** is more general, such as "I have money in the bank" which does not refer to cash.

Comment: If you have paid, then you _have_ used money, regardless of the format. Unusually, both of your examples mean pretty much exactly the same.